# Can't filter out 1.#INF values

Tags: mdx

```
SELECT NON EMPTY {{[Measures].[Net Promoter Score],[Measures].[AvgRevenuePerUnit]}} ON COLUMNS ,
NON EMPTY {{Hierarchize(DrilldownLevel(DrilldownLevel(DrilldownLevel([Employees].[Boss].[ALL]))))}} 
ON ROWS
FROM (SELECT ({[Employees].[Boss].&[14404]}) ON COLUMNS
FROM [Enterprise]
WHERE FILTER([Employees].[EID].[EID],[Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] > 700)) 
WHERE ({[Employees].[Active Status].&[False]},{[Roles].[Roster Role].&[486]},{[Roles].[Enterprise Role].&[2]},
{[Locations].[Location].&[6]},{[Areas].[Area].&[3]},{[Markets].[Market].&[1]},{[Regions].[Region].&[2]},
{[Dates].[Date].&[20130218]:[Dates].[Date].&[20130319]})
```

When I run above query, AvgRevenuePerUnit column shows 1.#INF. To replace 1.#INF with 0, I used query given below but the result is same. I am using WITH MEMBER in a query given below.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AvgRevenuePerUnit] AS (IIF([Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] = '1.#INF', 0, [Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit])), Format_String = '0.#0'
SELECT NON EMPTY {{[Measures].[Net Promoter Score],[Measures].[AvgRevenuePerUnit]}} ON COLUMNS ,
NON EMPTY {{Hierarchize(DrilldownLevel(DrilldownLevel(DrilldownLevel([Employees].[Boss].[ALL]))))}} 
ON ROWS
FROM (SELECT ({[Employees].[Boss].&[14404]})  ON COLUMNS
FROM [Enterprise] WHERE FILTER([Employees].[EID].[EID],[Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] > 700)) 
WHERE ({[Employees].[Active Status].&[False]},{[Roles].[Roster Role].&[486]},{[Roles].[Enterprise Role].&[2]},
{[Locations].[Location].&[6]},{[Areas].[Area].&[3]},{[Markets].[Market].&[1]},{[Regions].[Region].&[2]},
{[Dates].[Date].&[20130218]:[Dates].[Date].&[20130319]})
```

I have a cube provided by user and from that cube I query data. It seems to me that actual value in cube is not 1.#INF that's why it doesn't replace with 0. But what is that value if it is not 1.#INF.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

`1.#INF` or `-1.#INF` is how Analysis Services displays plus/minus infinity, which technically/mathematically is the result of dividing something by zero.

The best approach to avoid this is in the definition of the measure, which is probably in the calculation script of the cube.  You probably have there something like

```
CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measure].[AvgRevenuePerUnit] AS A / B
      , VISIBLE = 1;
```

Replace this with

```
CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measure].[AvgRevenuePerUnit] AS IIf(B <> 0, A / B, null)
      , VISIBLE = 1;
```

and you are done. Of course, replace `A` and `B` as appropriate.

Note: There was a recent update for Analysis Services 2012 which contains a new MDX function `Divide` which allows to write

```
CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.[Measure].[AvgRevenuePerUnit] AS Divide(A, B)
      , VISIBLE = 1;
```

If you and all other users really have to stick with the definition as it is in the cube, and have to rely on WITH clauses in queries, then I think your code could be written like

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[AvgRevenuePerUnit] AS
     IIF([Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] = 1 / 0         --  '1.#INF', plus infinity
            OR [Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] = -1 / 0, -- '-1.#INF', minus infinity
         0,
         [Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit]),
     Format_String = '0.#0'
...
```

Your approach of using `'1.#INF'` does not work, as this is a string, and the infinite numbers are numbers and not strings for Analysis Services.

Comment: I want one more thing. I want to filter out 1.#INF value from the query given above. How can I do this ?

Comment: @user2815197 To hide the infinite values, just use NULL instead of 0 as the replacement for the infinite values (second of the three parameters of the `IIF` in the `WITH` clause of my answer). Then the `NON EMPTY` of the rows would cause these rows to disappear.

Comment: @user2815197 Would you mind marking the answer as the accepted answer so that others can see the question is answered?

Comment: FrankPI, 
Rows not disappear but AvgRevenuePerUnit column disppeared. And now only [Net Promoter Score] columns shows. I have to filter out all rows not AvgRevenuePerUnit column.

Comment: @user2815197 Do you have `NON EMPTY` for the rows? Only then will rows having only `NULL` values disappear.

Comment: Yes, i have NON EMPTY clause in my query.

Comment: @user2815197 So you have non empty ***for the rows*** in your query, and there is a row with completely empty cells? Then you have found a bug in the software (Analysis Services? You did not tag which software you are using).

Comment: Analysis Service version is 10.50.1600.1. I have 2 columns in a row [Net Promoter Score] and [Avg Revenue Per Unit]. [Net Promoter Score] has numeric value but [Avg Revenue Per Unit] has 1.#INF value so NON EMPTY hides [Avg Revenue Per Unit] column only.

Comment: If you use `SELECT NON EMPTY foo ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY bar ON ROWS FROM [cube]`, then the first `NON EMPTY` means: omit columns that have NULL as their cell value for all rows, and the second `NON EMPTY` means: omit rows that have NULL as their cell value for all columns. Each of these `NON EMPTY`s can be missing, in which case all rows or all columns, including those having NULLS on all rows (if the NON EMPTY for the columns is missing) or on all columns (if the NON EMPTY for the rows is missing). `NON EMPTY` is **not** a statement setting, but an axis (rows/columns) setting!

Comment: I am working on this issue and its looking that it will be resolved soon. Just tell me is 1.#IND and NaN is also equal to 1/0 ?

Comment: `1.#INF` is the text that Analysis Services shows for infinity, which is something that you can get by dividing any number greater than zero by 0.0, e. g. `1.0 / 0.0`. `-1#IND` is how Analysis Services shows `NaN` (not a number), which you can get e. g. by dividing 0.0 by 0.0. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Special_values for an explanation of the concepts of non-standard floating point values.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Query working fine now. Results are correct but 1 problem arise as I alias columns in WITH MEMBER clause. In my c# code, I have to change those previous column names according to alias names. I can't change column names on C# because I have to change those column names with alias names in dozens of files which I don't know and it will make my application full of errors. How can  I use same previous column names. Can you help me again ?

Comment: @user2815197 As this is completely unrelated to the subject "Can't filter out 1.#INF values", I would suggest asking a new question. Please state clearly what is your query, what are the names you have, and what you need with regard to names.

Comment: Okay. I am asking another question with subject 'Alias MDX Query SSAS'

Comment: Please read my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239418/alias-mdx-query-ssas