# Alias MDX Query SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[NetPromoterScore] AS (IIF(([Measures].[Net Promoter Score] = 1/0 OR 
[Measures].[Net Promoter Score] = -1/0 OR ISEMPTY([Measures].[Net Promoter Score]) 
OR [Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] = 1/0 OR [Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] = -1/0 OR 
ISEMPTY([Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit]) ), NULL, [Measures].[Net Promoter Score])) 

MEMBER [Measures].[AvgRevenuePerUnit] AS (IIF(([Measures].[Net Promoter Score] = 1/0 
OR [Measures].[Net Promoter Score] = -1/0 OR ISEMPTY([Measures].[Net Promoter Score]) 
OR [Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] = 1/0 OR [Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit] = -1/0 
OR ISEMPTY([Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit]) ), NULL, [Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit]))

SELECT NON EMPTY
       { {[Measures].[NetPromoterScore],[Measures].[AvgRevenuePerUnit]} }
       ON COLUMNS ,
       NON EMPTY
       {{Hierarchize(DrilldownLevel({[Roles].[Enterprise Role].[ALL]}))}}
       DIMENSION  PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,  MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
       ON ROWS
  from Enterprise 
 WHERE (FILTER( [Employees].[EID].[EID],[Measures].[Avg Revenue Per Unit]> 700),
        {[Areas].[Area].&[3]},
        {[Markets].[Market].&[1]},{[Regions].[Region].&[2]},{[Locations].[Location].&[6],[Locations].[Location].&[6]},
        {[Dates].[Date].&[20130219]:[Dates].[Date].&[20130318]})
```

As you see I have aliased [Net Promoter Score] column name with [NetPromoterScore] and [Avg Revenue Per Unit] column name with [AvgRevenuePerUnit]. But in my C# code, the names used are [Net Promoter Score] and [Avg Revenue Per Unit] and I can't change these previous name with new aliased name because I have to make changes in dozens of files and then I have to test whole application. Can I alias twice in the query above to get same previous column names or can I without aliasing get the same result from the query above?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the sense of MDX, you have not aliased the members, but created new members.

I see two possibilities how you can solve this:

1. Move these calculations to the cube calculation script, i. e. rename
   the original measures in the cube, and define calculated measures
   with the name that you need and the same calculation that you have
   in your query. You would then make the original renamed measures
   invisible. This would be the best solution in my eyes, as it would
   let every cube user benefit from the improvement, without breaking
   external code or queries.
2. Depending on how exactly you reference the measures in your C# code
   (you did not post samples), you could just use the caption property
   of the measures, i. e. re-write the member definitions as follows:

   WITH MEMBER [Measures].[NetPromoterScore] AS IIF(...), CAPTION = 'Net Promoter Score'
        MEMBER [Measures].[AvgRevenuePerUnit] AS IIF(...), CAPTION = 'Avg Revenue Per Unit'

Comment: I can't use option 1. 
2nd option works on SSAS but on c#, dataset returns WITH MEMBER names not caption names. So problem not solved yet. Need more help :)

Comment: @user2815197 Sorry, but if the caption is not enough, then I have no idea how you can reach your aim without changing the cube.